# Install python module during runtime in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm trying to install python module/package during runtime in Azure functions without too much luck.
Installing the module with pip seems to work just fine, but getting the function (current python interpreter) to realize a new module has been isntalled is proving to be rather tricky.

This is minimum code to reproduce the issue::

```py
import io
import json
import logging
import sys

import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="InstallModule")
def install_module(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info("install_module was triggered")
    data = req.get_json()
    module_name = data.get("module")

    output = None
    try:
        import subprocess
        output = subprocess.run("pip install " + module_name, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
        logging.info(output)
        __import__(module_name)
        output = f"{output}\nwe have survived this"
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(f"Failed to execute got {ex}")

    return func.HttpResponse(str(output))
```

The first time the endpoint is triggerd with: POST /api/InstallModule w json body:

```json
{
    "module": "numpy"
}
```

the output looks something like:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable\nCollecting numpy\n  Downloading numpy-1.25.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (18.2 MB)\n     \xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81 18.2/18.2 MB 42.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00\nInstalling collected packages: numpy\nSuccessfully installed numpy-1.25.2\n
```

next time:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable\nRequirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.25.2)\n
```

But in both cases it will fail with error:

```
[Error]   Failed to execute got No module named 'numpy'
```

Runninc the same azure function localy works without issue, so it has to do something with the cacheing or permissions on the Azure Functions... Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

BTW it looks like azure functions are not using virtual environment, and pip install directory is in path:

```json
    "pip_V": "b'pip 23.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)\\n'",
    "sys_path": [
        "/tmp/functions\\standby\\wwwroot",
        "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages",
        "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64",
        "/usr/local/lib/python310.zip",
        "/usr/local/lib/python3.10",
        "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload",
        "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages",
        "/home/site/wwwroot"
    ],
```

I have tried checking python path, running pip freeze before and after and verify that the module does get installed, but I couldn't make python interpterer realize that the module is installed.

**EDIT 10.08.2023**

Hi @Sampath thank you so much for trying to help me with this one. Unfortunately, the issue is still there, I have created an entirely new project and copied everything (your entire code if you would like me to share the project please let me know) and published it. The first time I run it I get the:
[image]

but the second time I'm getting:
[image]

I can't help but wonder what is different in our setups? Is it something in the project settings or in the way I have created Azure Functions App? btw I have tried hosting options: Consumption and App service and both options behave the same way.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install python module during runtime in Azure Functions**

v1

```py
import  json
import  logging
import  sys
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  importlib  import  import_module
def  main(req:  func.HttpRequest)  ->  func.HttpResponse:
try:
req_body = req.get_json()
if  'module'  in  req_body:
module_name = req_body['module']
# Try importing the module directly
try:
import_module(module_name)
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Module '{module_name}' already available.")
except  ImportError:
pass
# Install the module using subprocess
output = install_module(module_name)
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Module '{module_name}' installed successfully.\n{output}")
else:
return  func.HttpResponse("Missing 'module' key in JSON payload .",  status_code=400)
except  Exception  as  e:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}",  status_code=500)
def  install_module(module):
try:
import  subprocess
output = subprocess.run([sys.executable,  "-m",  "pip",  "install",  module],  capture_output=True,  text=True,  check=True)
return  output.stdout
except  Exception  as  ex:
return  f"Failed to execute got {ex}"
```

v2

```
import json
import logging
import sys
import subprocess
import azure.functions as func
from importlib import import_module

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name("HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="req")  # Specify the route here
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        if 'module' in req_body:
            module_name = req_body['module']
            
            # Try importing the module directly
            try:
                import_module(module_name)
                return func.HttpResponse(f"Module '{module_name}' already available.")
            except ImportError:
                pass
            
            # Install the module using subprocess
            output = install_module(module_name)
            
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Module '{module_name}' installed successfully.\n{output}")
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("Missing 'module' key in JSON payload.", status_code=400)
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

def install_module(module):
    try:
        output = subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", module], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
        return output.stdout
    except Exception as ex:
        return f"Failed to execute got {ex}"
```

[image]
**In local:**

[image]

[image]
**In Azure:**
[image]

[image]

**In SSH:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sampath thank yous so much for trying to help me with this one.
Unfortunately, the issue is still there, I have created an entirely new project  and copied everything your entire code published it and the first time I run it I get:
```
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.25.2
```

but the second time I'm getting:
```
Module 'numpy' installed successfully.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.25.2)
```

Comment: Since SO doesn't allow uploading images in comments I have edited the original question to include them.

Comment: @OgnjenB.   setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` Value `1` according to [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#benefits-of-running-from-a-package-file) in [Configuration](https://i.imgur.com/aPPSt0T.png). run the application again it will install again since the configuration changes after once installed we get `Module 'numpy' already available`.

Comment: Hi @Sampath thank you for your help I appreciate you finding the time to help. It turns out that when you host Azure functions directly and do pip install, after which importing that module doesn't work. But if you do that from docker then it works just fine. Your comment made me realize that if it's working for you and not for me there has to be something different in the setup. BTW I have tried setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE  to 1 but it didn't help, unfortunately. Do you have any ideas about what could be different in those 3 environments so 2 (local and docker) work, but one doesn't?

Comment: you were testing under docker containers as well, right? Or there is something else different?

Comment: test in local, docker and azure. In Azure time work with `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE `  Value `1 `.   docker works just fine.

Comment: Hi @Sampath, sorry this might be a stupid question, but how do you set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE? Every time I have tried (either through Configuration page like on your screenshot or through azure cli), after saving settings all my endpoints disappear from the page and I have to redeploy the app. But when I redeploy it again (from VSCode or from azure cli) one of the first log messages is `Removing WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting (1)`. I have tried using Premium hosting plan, but same behavior.  So I'm not able to test whether or not this flag helps...

Comment: BTW the command I have used to publish was:
``func azure functionapp publish <func name>``
and for setting the flag:
`az functionapp config appsettings set -g <res name>-n <func name> --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1`

Comment: After redeploying the app we can add in configuration in azure portal (or) opening the function in visual studio code. Right click on App [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/includes/media/functions-vs-code-run-remote/execute-function-now.png) -> add settings click on it so we enter the name as `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` and value as `1`.